# React native flatlist rerender issue

Tags: react-native

I am facing an issue when rendering flatlist in react native .. while I need to refresh the flatlist when pull down to get the new data if found, also I am using the pagination as the following code .. but when I pull down the list it is not get the new data and "offset" remain increasing even if i setOffset(0) on the refreshcontrol function ..

can you help me plz...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import Background from '../components/Background'
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'
import axios from 'axios';

//import all the components we are going to use
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Alert,
  RefreshControl,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import { BASE_URL } from '../config';

export default function RequestsScreen() {

  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const [isListEnd, setIsListEnd] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const {userInfo} = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => getData(), []);

  const getData = () => {
    if (!loading && !isListEnd) {
      setLoading(true);
      console.log(`getData Run Using Offset (${offset})`);
      axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/requests`, {
        do:'_getRequests',userToken:userInfo.data.token,dataOffset:offset
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data.success === true) {
                if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
                    setOffset(offset + 3);
                    //After the response increasing the offset for the next API call.
                    setDataSource([...dataSource, ...res.data.data]);
                    setLoading(false);
                }
                else {
                    setIsListEnd(true);
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            }
            else {
                Alert.alert(`ERROR: ${res.data.message}`);
            }
            console.log(`New Offset (${offset})`);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(`Error in Loading Data: ${e}`);
        });
    }
  };

  const onRefresh = () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    setOffset(0);
    console.log(`onRefresh Run Using Offset (${offset})`);
    getData();
    setTimeout(() => {
      setRefreshing(false);
    }, 1000); // Refresh indicator will be visible for at least 1 second
  };

  const renderFooter = () => {
    return (
      //Footer View with Loader
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        {loading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator color="black" style={{ margin: 15 }} />
        ) : null}
      </View>
    );
  };

  const ItemView = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{padding:10,margin:5,backgroundColor:'#dddddd',borderRadius:4}}>
        <Text>{item.reg_code}</Text>
        <Text>{item.customer.en_name}</Text>
        <Text>{item.course}</Text>
        <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row',alignContent:'flex-start',marginTop:10}}>
          <Button onPress={() => getItem(item)} title="Details"></Button>
          <Button onPress={() => getItem(item)} title="Update Status"></Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const getItem = (item) => {
    //Function for click on an item
    Alert.alert('Id : ' + item.reg_id + ' Title : ' + item.reg_code);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, marginTop:30, padding:5 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={dataSource}
        extraData={dataSource}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={ItemView}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
        onEndReached={getData}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} colors={['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff','#3ad564']} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    footer: {
      padding: 10,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      flexDirection: 'row',
    },
  });
```

I tried everything to set the offset by zero when I pull the list down but with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setOffset` triggers a re-render and when that happens `offset` is updated. One way to accomplish offset reset is to add offset to dependencies in `useEffect` and remove the direct call to `getData`. After every re-render with changed dependencies, `getData` will run with the new values.

```
useEffect(() => getData(), [offset]);
```